# Асинхронность python не работает таймер

Tags: python, async-await

```
from asyncio import create_task, get_event_loop, sleep


class Timer:
    def __init__(self, color: bool):
        self.seconds: int = 900
        self.expires: bool = color
        self.color = lambda x: "белых" if color else "чёрных"
        get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.start_timer())

    async def start_timer(self):
        """Запускает цикл событий"""
        
        await create_task(self.update_timer())

    async def update_timer(self):
        """Ведёт время отсчёта"""

        while self.seconds:
            if self.expires:
                self.seconds -= 1
                await sleep(1)

        assert self.seconds, f"Закончилось время у {self.color}. Противоположный игрок победил"

    def flip_the_timer(self):
        """Меняет положение таймера (активный/деактивный)"""

        self.expires = not self.expires

    def get_timeset(self) -> str:
        """:return время в виде таймера на электронных часах"""

        return f"{round(self.seconds / 60)}:{self.seconds % 60}"
```

Проблемный код выше

У меня всегда были проблемы с асинхронностью, но всегда по тихоньку прорывался, но на этой неделе встретил какой-то убийственный случай

Таймер запускается, ошибок не ловлю, но даже в силу асинхронности код не идёт дальше, а тупо ждёт таймер, при этом конкурентно должен запуститься второй таймер, но он не появляется

Создал таску, запустил, как только не пробовал решить проблему.

Товарищи программисты дружащие с асинхронностью, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Логичный вопрос — а вы проверяли, что условие `if self.expires:` вообще выполняется?

Comment: @andreymal да, дебажил, всё выполняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример использования asyncio.loop:

```py
from asyncio import sleep, new_event_loop


async def task1():
    for i in range(15):
        print(f'task {i}')
        await sleep(1)


async def main():
    print('main1')
    await sleep(2)
    print('main2')
    await sleep(2)
    print('main3')
    await sleep(2)

loop = new_event_loop()

task_main = loop.create_task(main())
task_1 = loop.create_task(task1())

loop.run_until_complete(task_1)
```

Результат:

```
main1
task 0
task 1
main2
task 2
task 3
main3
task 4
task 5
task 6
task 7
task 8
task 9
task 10
task 11
task 12
task 13
task 14

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Но в вашем случае я думаю лучше подходит threading:

```py
import time
from threading import Thread


class Timer:
    def __init__(self, color: bool):
        self.seconds: int = 900
        self.expires: bool = color
        self.color = lambda x: "белых" if color else "чёрных"
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update_timer)
        self.thread.start()

    def update_timer(self):
        """Ведёт время отсчёта"""

        while self.seconds:
            if self.expires:
                self.seconds -= 1
                time.sleep(1)

        assert self.seconds, f"Закончилось время у {self.color}. Противоположный игрок победил"

    def flip_the_timer(self):
        """Меняет положение таймера (активный/деактивный)"""

        self.expires = not self.expires

    def get_timeset(self) -> str:
        """:return время в виде таймера на электронных часах"""

        return f"{round(self.seconds / 60)}:{self.seconds % 60}"


timer = Timer(True)
print('Do something....')
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Сделал все через многопоточность, надеюсь +- пойдёт.